# How could life exist underneath a world too small for a magnetic field?

Tags: planets, aliens, geology

In a new documentary made by melodysheep called [LIFE BEYOND II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThDYazipjSI&t=272s): The Museum of Alien Life, the creator proposed there could be life on a planet too small for a magnetic field beneath the surface.

But how could this work? If there isn't a magnetic field, wouldn't there not be enough geothermal heat for that to be an option?

Comment: How is that not off-topic as a real-world Question, as barred by Worldbuilding SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A magnetic field and geothermal heat are not necessarily interdependent.

If you have a molten core of magnetic element (iron and nickel in Earth case) then the dependence is present. But if your core is molten and not magnetic, you have the heat without the magnetic field.

Moreover, you can have geothermal heat as a consequence of tidal forces, without having an intrinsic heat source in the form of a hot core.

Comment: I hadn't considered that

Comment: Or the Venus scenario, it's hotter than your oven but has no magnetic field.

Comment: Really? Didn't know that